# How create single object from Multiple number of objects using javascript or Lodash

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js, lodash

I have an object Like this

```
var Data= {
  "firstname": {
    "excelcolumnName": "firstName",
    "dbcolumn": "one",
    "testinfo": "basictest"
  },
  "labname": {
    "excelcolumnName": "LabName",
    "dbcolumn": "two",
    "testinfo": "basictest"
  },
  "percentCbd": {
    "excelcolumnName": "Percent CBD",
    "dbcolumn": "three",
    "testinfo": "Final Test"
  }

  "percentgeneral": {
    "excelcolumnName": "Percent General",
    "dbcolumn": "four",
    "testinfo": "Final Test"
  }
}
```

i want filter and create new object that contain **testinfo:"basictest"** the output of single object should be like this.

```
{
"one":"basictest",
"two":"basictest"
}
```

can any body help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you want a single object containing dbcolumn:testinfo mappings

[Check this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/rehuve/160/edit?html,js,console,output)

```
var Data2={};

_.map(Data,(obj)=>{
  if(obj.testinfo==='basictest'){
  var newObj={};
  newObj[obj.dbcolumn]=obj.testinfo;
  return _.assign(Data2,newObj);
  }
});
console.log(Data2);
```

The map function 'maps' each object into something else. The assign merges these key-value pairs. The newObj[obj.dbcolumn] line converts the value from 'dbcolumn:value' into a key for the new object.

Comment: WIth lodash, you can use function chaining on arrays - not sure if it works on objects like your Data - Check this link https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2015/05/14/implicit-function-chains-in-lodash

Comment: With chaining, you could have done _(Data).filter(function to filter out only basic tests).map(to get only dbcolumn:testinfo mappings)

Answer (score 0):

```
Var array = [];

for(var i=0;i<Object.keys(Data).length;i++){
  if(data[i].testinfo === 'basictest'){ 
    array.push(data[i]);
  }
}
```

array will have all objects with `testinfo = 'basictest'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const Data = {
  "firstname": {
    "excelcolumnName": "firstName",
    "dbcolumn": "one",
    "testinfo": "basictest"
  },
  "labname": {
    "excelcolumnName": "LabName",
    "dbcolumn": "two",
    "testinfo": "basictest"
  },
  "percentCbd": {
    "excelcolumnName": "Percent CBD",
    "dbcolumn": "three",
    "testinfo": "Final Test"
  },
  "percentgeneral": {
    "excelcolumnName": "Percent General",
    "dbcolumn": "four",
    "testinfo": "Final Test"
  }
}

const result = {} // contain result

for (var i in Data) {
 const item = Data[i]
 result[item.dbcolumn] = item.testinfo // add a new object item
}

console.log(result) // print {one: "basictest", two: "basictest", three: "Final Test", four: "Final Test"}
```